# What should the ending be?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

The sentence is Сегодня страна является одним из 21 участник(-?) международного соглашения.
What should the ending of the noun be and why?

An addition 
Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Слово страна-участница есть в русском литературном языке (оно зафиксировано, например, в «Русском орфографическом словаре» РАН). Но в строгом стиле письменной речи, в деловых документах даже по отношению к лицам женского пола используются существительные мужского рода (а страна – и вовсе неодушевленное существительное). Поэтому при вариативности страна-участница и страна-участник в официальных документах лучше всё же использовать форму мужского рода: страна – участник договора (если после слова участница / участник есть зависимое слово, используется не дефис, а тире).

Comment: With 21, участницы

Comment: Для устранения диссонансов лучше переформулировать предложение, напр. _Сегодня страна является полноправной 21 (двадцать первой) участницей межд. соглашения_.

Comment: Для вопросов на русском есть отдельный сайт - http://rus.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @enkryptor, OK,  what should the ending of the noun be after the numeral "21"? Do I pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то, поскольку "участник" можно поставить в любой род, и состав всего коллектива стостоит только из стран (т.е. понятий ж.р.), правильнее говорить "одной из ... участниц" (в общем случае). Но в случае "21" согласовяние идет, как всегда, с последним словом:

> Сегодня страна является одной из двадцати одной участницы международного соглашения.

Единственная проблема только в том, что *одной из двадцати одной участницы* звучит бестолково из-за повтора. Тогда, если в м.р., то обычное согласование с "один" в род.п.:

> ...одним из [двадцати|пятидесяти|N] одного участника

Answer (score 6):

Если заменить в предложении число на числительное (что необходимо при произнесении предложения), то сложно себе представить иное окончание, кроме `-а`.

> Сегодня страна является одним из двадцати одного участника международного соглашения.

Answer (score 0):

Страна, конечно же, будет участницей, а не участником, так как слово "страна" женского рода. Но вопрос, я так понимаю о том, в каком числе должно быть слово после числительного. Правило простое: если числительное в тектовой форме заканчивается на "один" ("один", "двадцать один" и т.д.), то слово к которому это числительное относится будет в единственном числе

> один мальчик,
>
> двадцать одна девочка
>
> и т.д.

Это не совсем исключение, но стоит обратить внимание, что 11 (211 и т.д.) хоть и заканчиваются на 1, в текстовой форме выглядят как "одиннадцать", "двести одиннадцать", и т.д., то есть не заканчиваются на "один". Поэтому

> одиннадцать девочек,
>
> сто одиннадцать мальчиков,
>
> двести тридцать жирафов.

После определения рода и числа нужно определить падеж и склонить сущствительное соответственно, но это уже совсем другая тема.